# Create custom winforms container

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, containers

I want to create a control in winforms with same behavior as the container controls.
I mean: in design mode, when I drop controls in it, it will group then, just like a groupbox.

This control I'm creating contains some other controls AND a GroupBox.
All I need is: when a control is droped in design mode over my custom control, I'll just put it inside the nested GroupBox.

But I can't figure out how make my control respond to that kind of action in design mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37830/Designing-Nested-Controls) is what you need, I found it at CodeProject a time ago:

> **Designing Nested Controls:**
>
> This article demonstrates how to allow a Control, which is a child of
>   another Control to accept having controls dropped onto it at design
>   time. It is not a large article, there is not much by way of code, and
>   this may not be either the 'official' or best way to do this. It does,
>   however, work, and is stable as far as I have been able to test it.

Comment: That's very nice! Thanks a lot! Trying to find out how to avoid that mentioned drawback without having the GroupBox permanently locked.

Comment: Using the above solution and Overriding the two `CanParent` methods from the `ParentControlDesigner` to always `return false`, I can block user trying to add controls outside the `WorkingArea`. That blocks user trying to move the `WorkingArea` as well. Now I need to block resizing of that area. With that, I believe answer is sufficient, not perfect though.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add a [Designer attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerattribute.aspx) to your control, and use a type that derives from or is the [ParentControlDesigner Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.parentcontroldesigner.aspx) (needs a reference to the System.Design.dll assembly), like this:

```
[Designer(typeof(MyCustomControlDesigner1))]
public partial class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        MyBox = new GroupBox();
        InitializeComponent();
        MyBox.Text = "hello world";
        Controls.Add(MyBox);
    }

    public GroupBox MyBox { get; private set; }
}

public class MyCustomControlDesigner1 : ParentControlDesigner
{
    // When a control is parented, tell the parent is the GroupBox, not the control itself
    protected override Control GetParentForComponent(IComponent component)
    {
        CustomControl1 cc = (CustomControl1)Control;
        return cc.MyBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats true - but that does not solve how the items will be dropped in  the nested groupbox

Comment: That's a very good start. If my box fills the entire control, all I should do now is figure out how to add some borders like those of the GroupBox. (+1)

Comment: But if the box is only part of the control, further knowledge is needed.

Comment: @Daniel: if you want to fill entire control with the groupbox, you probably better derive from GroupBox.

Comment: There are other child controls that wont appear if I do that.

Comment: @Daniel - I have updated my answer to make the inner GroupBox the parent of dropped controls

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change the behavior. Added controls are still in the major control area, getting dropped behind the GroupBox.

Comment: Surely. Copied exactly just in case.

Comment: In fact, `GetParentForComponent` isn't being called, I've overriden the `Initialize` and `OnDragDrop` as well to test. Put a messagebox to be shown on each of the three to confirm that.

Comment: Ok, so you're not using my code as is. My code answers your initial question I believe.

Comment: I did use your code as is. `GetParentForComponent` never gets called by the designer. The other overridings I did later just to prove that. `Initialize` gets called. `OnDragDrop` gets called. `CanParent` gets called. `Control {get;}` gets called. But `GetParentForComponent` is never called in any case.